# kill/stop all Google Chrome processes

Tags: chrome

I like Chrome and such, I don't really want to switch back to Firefox or anything else.

My issue is that occasionally it really feels like the whole process needs a restart. I've noticed that if I just close it and close its little bubble in the top-right, processes (`ps -A`) stick around.

Is there a quick/easy way I could just create a button that says "nuke chrome" and kill all processes related to it with one click?

I think it would be helpful.

Using Xubuntu 14.04 and no longer stuck on it, so it's even alright with me if you're like:

> "Try this other distro that won't have those sorts of issues."

Yes, it probably is one of these many buggy extensions I've installed. But I'd like to use this same method with other applications as well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: instead of **nuke** if you write **kill/stop** it will be easier for others to find this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to Chrome settings --> "Show advanced settings" and uncheck "Continue running background apps when Chrome is closed", that might solve the problem.

Otherwise, you could use the command `pgrep chrome | xargs kill` or `pkill chrome` (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/30421/151944)).

[These](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/05/13/linux-xubuntu-howto-create-app-launcher-on-main-menu/) two [links](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688841#4) both explains how to create a launcher (menu button) in Xfce (Xubuntu). Just create a launcher for either of the two above commands, after testing them in a terminal to make sure they do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/bin/pkill --oldest --signal TERM -f chrome
```

details:

- `TERM` is the same as signal `15`, hence `--signal TERM`
- we want to signal only the root chrome process, hence `--oldest`
- in my tests, `/usr/bin/wmctrl` did not work to exit chrome